# Debugging a rqt plugin in PyCharm

Tags: rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I am developing a rqt plugin in Python at the moment and I am using the recommended IDE PyCharm.

When I get errors I always try to debug with print messages.

I am wondering is there a good debugging solution to debug a rqt plugin in PyCharm?

Thank you very much in advance!

Best regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/248227/debugging-a-rqt-plugin-in-pycharm/) by [ce_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28528/ce_guy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2016-11-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I realized now that I can debug my plugins by using the "Attach to Local Process" function (you can find it under "Run") and attach it to the rqt process. I had to change the ptrace settings to make it work by:

$ sudo su -

$ echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope

found here: http://blog.mellenthin.de/archives/2010/10/18/gdb-attach-fails-with-ptrace-operation-not-permitted/#comment-141535

Maybe it'll help someone.

---

Originally posted by [ce_guy](https://answers.ros.org/users/28528/ce_guy/) with karma: 77 on 2017-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1